# Trying to update a table related to multiple other rows in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table which represents a tree using nested sets with the typical left and right columns (trLeft and trRight). For  optimization, I also include the row's level in the tree, which is the number of parents it has up to the tree ROOT.

In nested sets the Parents of a row A are all other rows B where `B.trLeft < A.trLeft AND B.trRight > A.trRight`.

So counting those rows will return the level, resulting in the following update query for a start in order to update all rows with the correct level:

```
UPDATE Groups AS g1 SET g1.trLevel = ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Groups AS g2 WHERE g2.trLeft < g1.trLeft AND g2.trRight > g1.trRight ) ;
```

but this results in Error 1093 "You can't specify target table 'g1' for update in FROM clause.

Is there a way to get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

A silly workaround is to nest a derived table inside a subquery, like so:

```
UPDATE Groups AS g1 
SET g1.trLevel = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM Groups AS g2 
  ) AS temp
  WHERE 
    temp.trLeft < g1.trLeft 
    AND temp.trRight > g1.trRight 
);
```

I tested this by first building the table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Groups (trLeft int, trRight int, trLevel int);

INSERT INTO Groups (trLeft, trRight) VALUES (1, 4), (5, 6), (2, 3);
```

and it works.

Comment: Unfortunately the same comment as for the previous poster. The "inside" query is NOT a subquery but a derived table, that's also why it requires a name (AS temp). In a derived table one cannot reference outer query columns.

Comment: Found that mySQL also locates the conflict in the nested queries. I modified your query avoiding the derivate table problem by moving the condition to a WHERE clause:  

`UPDATE Groups AS g1 
SET g1.trLevel = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM Groups AS g2 
  ) AS g3
  WHERE 
      g3.trLeft < g1.trLeft 
      AND g3.trRight > g1.trRight 

);`  

This results in the same initial 1093 error code

Comment: You're right, I couldn't test at the time but now I can.  I edited my answer.  It's pretty much identical to your reply, but it's working in my db.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Does still not work for me, for the same reason. You are not testing on mySQL, are you ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MySQL.  Are you not?  Your tag says MySQL

Comment: Yes, I am, well correctly speaking I am using mariaDB 5.5-33, but I am wondering why this would work for you but not for me.

Comment: Hmm.  Don't know what to tell you =\ I tried looking up error 1093 for MariaDB but didn't find much.  I know MySQL and MariaDB are basically the same thing, but all I can figure is it must be due to some difference between them.  Maybe add a MariaDB tag and see if someone with specific MariaDB experience can help?

Comment: Which version of MySQL did you use for the test ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort of nest the count in a select. I think this will work:

`EDITED: Updated query`

```
UPDATE Groups SET trLevel = (
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Groups g2 inner join Groups g1 on g2.unique_id = g1.unique_id WHERE g2.trLeft < g1.trLeft AND g2.trRight > g1.trRight 
    ) AS my_count
) ;
```

The `AS my_count` is important because it tells MySQL to create a tmp table from this query. The my_count tmp table is then used as the source for the UPDATE statement.

Comment: thanks for th esuggestion, but does not work. Th ereason is that with AS my_count you create a derived table which canot reference columns from the main query, resulting in error 1054 "Unknown column t1.trLeft in where clause"

Comment: My bad, please see my updated query. Essentially, we are joining two columns from the same table (as you can see). The reason this should work is that we're defining g1 and g2 in the derived table.

Comment: I cant see how this could solve the problem. I understand unique_id to be a unique ID of a row, i.e. the primary key. If so, you join the same row which results in the where clause to be always false, and the count 0.  Further as all is defined in the derived table there is no link between the actually updated row and the derived table result, i.e. the result can't be valid in scope.